# Scan a receipt and recognize text/numeric data on it

Tags: windows, ocr, finance, microsoft-excel, scanning

I'm looking for a software that can scan a receipt to retrieve data of total price, product's name and price, receipt date and receipt number.

Some important criteria:

- The software can be created as a open source or not.
- Simple to use
- If possible, the software is free to use for private purpose.
- You can retrieve the data and save it as a excel file.
- I want to use the software on Windows.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: I think asker mentioned Windows.

Comment: Are price/text/etc always at the same place?

Comment: There are two different receipt due to different store.

Answer (score 3):

[queXF](http://quexf.sourceforge.net/) is an Open Source, web based paper form verification and data entry system:

[image: queXF]

It requires you to first express your paper-printed form in the queXML format.

queXF then uses this "schema" to recognize fields of the scanned image.
Not sure about the Excel format.

Free, Open source, seems well-maintained (last release 2 months ago).

Answer (score 2):

For a complete (Scan, Capture and Document Management) and affordable solution, look at Librex.

It covers your requirements. You'll be able to scan your receipts, extract the metatadata our of them, and then search the recepit per metadata. In the search results, you may copy the metadata and paste in Excel, so for that requirement, it would be a "two step" operation.

More info in this PDF: http://www.coriumsoft.com/images/stories/librex%20edms.pdf

You can install it by yourself here (or ask Corium for support): http://www.coriumsoft.com/confluence/display/librexEN/Librex+Quick+Start+Guide

Librex also offers a free version (with 30$ donation to Room to Read) for up to 2000 captured pages per year, which should fit your scenario, and an Enterprise version for larger volumes.

For full transparency, please note that I'm working at Corium.

Thanks, Marc

Comment: If you are affiliated in any way with the program, please mention in your answer(s).